# Python odeint, solution returning array of initial conditions

Tags: scipy, odeint

> See code below

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.integrate import odeint

    # Define constants
    U = 1000    
    a = 5    
    Ta0 = (37+273)   
    V_tot = 6 
    FA0 = 14.7   
    CA0 = 9.3  
    deltaCp = 0
    Hrx_T = -6900
    sumTheta_Cp = 159

    #Integration conditions

    V = np.linspace(0,V_tot,10) 
    X0 = 0
    T0 = 310

    #Define reaction rate constant as function of temperature 
    def k(T):
        return 31.1*np.exp(7906*((T-360)/(T*360)))

    def Kc(T):
        return 3.03*np.exp(-830.3*((T-333)/(T*333)))

    #Define rate law as function of temperature, conversion 

    def rA(T,X):
        return -k(T)*CA0*(1-(1+(1/Kc(T))*X))


    #Energy balance equation for tubular reactor

    def ode_vector(diff_var,V):

        T = diff_var[0]
        X = diff_var[1]                          

        dT_dV=(U*a*(Ta0-T)+rA(T,X)*Hrx_T/(FA0*sumTheta_Cp+deltaCp*X))
        dX_dV= -rA(T,X)/FA0

        d_dV = [dT_dV,dX_dV]

        return d_dV

    initial_vector = [T0, X0]

    solution = odeint(ode_vector,initial_vector,V)

print solution
```

> When I execute this code I get an array of my initial conditions
>
> [[ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]
>   [ 310.    0.]]
>
> Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: (1) From your use of the `print` statement I infer that you are using Python 2.  You can save yourself some headaches by putting `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script, so all division gives floating point results.  Otherwise, an expression such as `3/2` gives `1`, not `1.5`. (2) Test the output of `ode_vector` (e.g. take a look at `ode_vector(initial_vector, V[0])`.  If it always returns [0,0], the solution generated by `odeint` will be a constant, equal to the initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I apologize for not provided a complete description. I'm new to Python and stackoverflow and will definitely work to clean up my questions so that they are addressed correctly.

Comment: I was able to trace the error back to a misplaced parenthesis in the rA(T,X) equation that was causing a [0,0] array for the ode_vector equation. My function is now working correctly.